# Xamarin Layout XAML

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, xamarin

I am currently building an application with Xamarin for IOS and Android, and it's supposed to be a converter application that converts decimals to binary, hex and octal equivalents.The application is supposed to be formatted a specific way, and I am very new to XAML. I want the labels to be centered on the screen and everything to be spaced out nicely, but the way I am doing it now makes it look messy. Below is my XAML. What are some properties or different layouts available in XAML that I could utilize, and could you please provide some examples? There is also an attachment at the bottom w/ the screen display currently.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Assignment2"
             x:Class="Assignment2.MainPage">

    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Padding="20">
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Label Text="Number Converter" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
            </StackLayout>
            <Label Text="Decimal" VerticalOptions="End" />

            <Entry x:Name="Decimal" WidthRequest="75" HorizontalOptions="Center" />
        </StackLayout>

        <BoxView x:Name ="Space" HeightRequest="30"/>

        <Button Clicked="Button_Clicked" x:Name="converter" Text="Convert" />

        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">

            <Label Text="Octal" VerticalOptions="Center" />

            <Label x:Name="Octal" VerticalOptions="Center" WidthRequest="100" />
            <Label Text="Hexadecimal" VerticalOptions="Center"/>

            <Label x:Name="Hexa" VerticalOptions="Center" WidthRequest="50" />
        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Label Text="Binary Bytes 1-4" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout>
            <BoxView x:Name="Extra" HeightRequest="30"/>
            <Label x:Name="First" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
            <Label x:Name="Second" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
            <Label x:Name="Third" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
            <Label x:Name="Forth" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

[Phone Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JBnut.png)

Comment: consider using a Grid instead of nested StackLayouts

Answer (score 0):

This is too broad of a question. 
I suggest you do some reading of the documentation about the layouts that are available to you. Then you can look at the docs for each layout type to see how to use them.

Overview: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/controls/layouts

ScrollView: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.scrollview?view=xamarin-forms
StackLayout: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.stacklayout?view=xamarin-forms
Grid: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.grid?view=xamarin-forms
AbsoluteLayout: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.absolutelayout?view=xamarin-forms
RelativeLayout (Expensive on performance, use with care): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.relativelayout?view=xamarin-forms
FlexLayout: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.flexlayout?view=xamarin-forms